# Access to a temp directory already created

Tags: java

currently I'm using `File fTemp = com.google.common.io.Files.createTempDir();` to create a temporary path, then carry that path to another bunch of methods as parameter.

I was wondering if there's a way to recover that temporary path, using a utils or something.

So, my method is:

```
private String environmentSetup() {     
    File fTemp = Files.createTempDir();
    fTemp.deleteOnExit();

    return fTemp.getPath();
}
```

Then I pass it as parameter to any other method could need that temp dir:

```
public void someMethod(final String tempPath, ...) {

    //do something

}
```

I was curious about there's a way to recover that unique temp dir without passing its path as parameter every time. Something like this after creating that directory:

```
public void someMethod(...){

//any function to get fTemp path from somewhere which isn't created fTemp itself

//do something

}
```

It's mostly a matter of style, curious about there's a way to do something like this.

Comment: Keep the `fTemp` variable?

Comment: Yes, in fact I return fTemp path as a variable to use it and provide it to another methods. I was wondering if I could do something like I try to describe above (I edited the original question to try to clarify it)

Comment: You could make `fTemp`  a member of the class.

Comment: The problem is, I provide it also to services outside this bundle, so turn `fTemp` into a field isn't the best option, but totally valid if the variable would be used locally only, of course. Call it at the outside service with a getter isn't a desirable way to do it, neither.

Comment: Making a temporary file available to "services outside this bundle" sounds like a data leak which is a hint for bad design. Wrap access to the temporary file into a proper method and expose *that*.

Comment: You could store the path in a preference file and read that key wherever it is needed.